# Why is this transformation not regarded as a symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

Problem 4.3 in *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering* by M. Blennow asks us to find the symmetries of a parallelogram tiling of the plane:

[image: Parallelogram tiling]

The solutions manual lists the following types of symmetry transformations: translations along either edge direction by a multiple of the side length, and 180° rotations about a vertex, the midpoint of an edge, or about the midpoint of a parallelogram. The different types of rotations can all be related by translations, so all of the above can be generated by the transformations $T_1$, $T_2$, and $c$ illustrated below:

[image: Generators of the given symmetries]

However, **I think that there should be one more**. To get a non-ambiguous characterization of it, let us pick some vertex as the origin and introduce a basis as below:

[image: Origin and basis]

Then, of course, each point in the plane can be uniquely identified as $x^1 \vec e_1 + x^2 \vec e_2$, for some $x^1, x^2 \in \mathbb R$, and we can define a transformation $\sigma$ by its action
$$x^1 \vec e_1 + x^2 \vec e_2 \mapsto -x^1 \vec e_1 + x^2 \vec e_2.$$
It seems to me that $\sigma$ is a symmetry of the tiling. Moreover, it cannot be constructed from the generators already listed, because it is not parity conserving (i.e., as a linear transformation it has negative determinant).

So, **why is $\sigma$ not regarded as a symmetry transformation**? Is there some conventional restriction on the types of transformations that we regard as symmetry transformations that forbids $\sigma$?

---

One commenter did not believe that the pattern is invariant under $\sigma$, so here is a short proof. In the introduced basis each horizontal line can be written as
$$H_n=\{r\vec e_1+n\vec e_2:r\in\mathbb R\}$$
for some integer $n$. Similarly each "skew-vertical" line can be written
$$V_n=\{n\vec e_1+r\vec e_2:r\in\mathbb R\}.$$
Hence
$$\sigma:H_n\mapsto\{-r\vec e_1+n\vec e_2:r\in\mathbb R\}=H_n$$
and
$$\sigma:V_n\mapsto\{-n\vec e_1+r\vec e_2:r\in\mathbb R\}=V_{-n}.$$

Comment: Any (reversible) variable change that helps solve the poroblem (for, example, separate variables) is useful in practice; don't stick to symmetries - they represent too narrow case of variable changes.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Sure, but I don't quite see how that is relevant in this case, because the problem is specifically about finding symmetries.

Comment: Because after your horizontal flip, the pattern is not the same as the original pattern and hence isn't a symmetry.

Comment: @Triatticus I think you are visualizing this incorrectly. It isn't quite a horizontal flip.

Comment: It is, making $x^1 \to -x^1$ is the exact definition of a horizontal flip. It's the equivalent of holding a mirror up to the left side of the image, and that mirror image doesn't match the original.

Comment: @Triatticus Only in an orthogonal basis, which is not the case here. Give me a minute and I will add a short proof to my question.

Comment: Isn't it just a special case of the translation transformation ? You are effectively simply adding $-2r \vec e_1 $ or $-2 n \vec e_1$.

Comment: @HansWurst No, it is more like a reflection (but not quite since it is not orthogonal). As you say, a point $x^1\vec e_1+x^2\vec e_2$ is translated by $-2x^1\vec e_1$, but, since this is $x^1$-dependent, points on different lines are are translated by different amounts. A translation transformation on the other hand translates the whole plane equally.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group. "The types of transformations that are relevant here are called Euclidean plane isometries". Your transformation is not an isometry because angle $\theta$ changes to $180-\theta$. Isometries must preserve length and angle.

Comment: @isometry I think this might be it! Then this is indeed a "conventional restriction on the types of transformations that we regard as symmetry transformations" as I suspected. It is strange that this isn't spelled out in the resources I have seen. Feel free to make your comment into an answer.

Comment: It's same $180^{\circ}$ rotational symmetry only along $y$ axis.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Had to think, but no it is not. That would rotate $e_2$ as well. I think we can say that extending from 2D to 3D isometries does not increase the number of solutions.

Comment: You said that in your question! This transformation is not parity preserving, you can use it, but then you have to pay attention when you transform [axial vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector). This is one of the reasons why sometimes this kind of transformations are not even mentioned,  but I don't know if this is the case for the author of the book you are referring to.

Comment: I just noticed that the issue with axial vectors really exists only in 3 dimensions, so it doesn't really apply to your case. So this weakens a lot my answer, but maybe the author is just silently assuming that he wants parity-preserving transformation because it is sometimes standard practice in physics.

Comment: @isometry _That would rotate $e_2$ as well_. **NO** it's not, 3D rotation about $y$ axis will flip $x,z$ axis, but NOT $y$ (aka $e_2$), cause we rotate about it - it's fixed !. You are clearly wrong.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Ok we had different meaning of y. Yes you can hold $e_2$ fixed and transform x,z. But that is not a rotation. You cant do it with a physical solid object. Unless $e_2$ is orthogonal to x,z.

Comment: @isometry. Yes, I had in mind that all axis are perpendicular to each other, in such case - it is a rotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [wallpaper group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group). "The types of transformations that are relevant here are called Euclidean plane isometries". Your transformation is not an isometry because the angle θ between $e_1$ and $e_2$ changes to 180−θ. Isometries must preserve length and angle.

Mathematically we can (and physicists often do) consider larger symmetry groups than Isometry Groups. For example transformations which preserve angle but not length form the Conformal Group; smooth reversible transformations which preserve neither angle or length form the Diffeomorphism Group.

We can also consider isometry groups which preserve length and angle with respect to a metric other than the Euclidean metric. For example in Special Relativity the appropriate isometry group is called the Lorentz Group.

Comment: This seems to be it. It seems a bit arbitrary though, since the reason that $\theta=\vec e_1\angle\vec e_2\mapsto\sigma(\vec e_1)\angle\sigma(\vec e_2)=\pi-\theta$ is that vectors have an orientation (a notion of backwards and forwards), and the vectors are not fundamental to the pattern, but something we imposed. The lines themselves do not have that, and the angle between two lines could be said to be conserved by the transformation because the pattern looks the same after the transformation.

Comment: Agree. But the reason isometries are interesting is because you can physically apply them to solid objects (directly in the case of translations and rotations; for reflections you need to flip the paper). So yes your transformation does preserve the pattern, but it does not belong to the set of such rigid actions.

Comment: That is a fair point! However, we cannot physically apply a reflection to a solid object either, yet we commonly consider reflective symmetry transformations.